# gawk or grep: single line and ungreedy

Tags: java, regex, awk, grep, git-bash

I'd like to print headers of `*.java` files in all sub-directories recursively that have more than two type parameters (i.e. parameters within `<R ... H>` in the samples below). One of the files looks like (with names reduced for brevity):

**multiple-lines.java**

```java
class ClazzA<R extends A,
    S extends B<T>, T extends C<T>,
    U extends D, W extends E,
    X extends F, Y extends G, Z extends H>
    extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<Q, R> x) { 
    // ... code ...
  }
}
```

with expected output:

```
ClazzA.java:10: class ClazzA<R extends A,
ClazzA.java:11:     S extends B<T>, T extends C<T>,
ClazzA.java:12:     U extends D, W extends E,
ClazzA.java:13:     X extends F, Y extends G, Z extends H>
ClazzA.java:14:     extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {
```

but another could look like this, as well:

**single-line.java**

```java
class ClazzB<R extends A, S extends B<T>, T extends C<T>, U extends D, W extends E, X extends F, Y extends G, Z extends H> extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<Q, R> x) { 
    // ... code ...
  }
}
```

with expected output:

```
ClazzB.java:42: class ClazzB<R extends A, S extends B<T>, T extends C<T>, U extends D, W extends E, X extends F, Y extends G, Z extends H> extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {
```

Files that should not be considered/printed:

**X-no-parameter.java**

```java
class ClazzC /* no type parameter */ extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<A, B> x) { 
    // ... code ...
  }
}
```

**X-one-parameter.java**

```java
class ClazzD<R extends A>  // only one type parameter
    extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<X, Y> x) { 
    // ... code ...
  }
}
```

**X-two-parameters.java**

```java
class ClazzE<R extends A, S extends B<T>>  // only two type parameters
    extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<X, Y> x) { 
    // ... code ...
  }
}
```

**X-two-line-parameters.java**

```java
class ClazzF<R extends A,  // only two type parameters
    S extends B<T>>        // on two lines
    extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<X, Y> x) { 
    // ... code ...
  }
}
```

All the spaces in the files could be `\s+`. `extends [...]` and `implements [...]` immediately prior to `{` are optional. `extends [...]` is also optional at each of the type parameters. See [The Java® Language Specification, 8.1. Class Declarations](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1) for details.

I'm using `gawk` in the *Git Bash*:

```bash
$ gawk --version
GNU Awk 5.0.0, API: 2.0 (GNU MPFR 4.0.2, GNU MP 6.2.0)
```

with:

```bash
find . -type f -name '*.java' | xargs gawk -f ws-class-type-parameter.awk > ws-class-type-parameter.log
```

and `ws-class-type-parameter.awk`:

```awk
# /start/ , /end/ ... pattern

#/class ClazzA<.*,.*/      , /{/  {    # 5 lines, OK for ClazzA, but in real it prints classes with 2 or less type parameters, too
#/class ClazzA<.*,.*,/     , /{/  {    # no line with ClazzA, since there's no second ',' on its first line
#/class ClazzA<.*,.*,/s    , /{/  {    # 500.000+(!) lines
#/class ClazzA<.*,.*,/s    , /{/U {    # 500.000+(!) lines
#/class ClazzA<.*,.*,/sU   , /{/U {    # 500.000+(!) lines
 /(?s)class ClazzA<.*,.*,/ , /{/  {    # no line

    match( FILENAME, "/.*/.." )
    print substr( FILENAME, RLENGTH ) ":" FNR ": " $0
}
```

This finds all the `*.java` files...great, executes `gawk` with each of them...great, but you see the results as comments after my tries. Please note: The `ClazzA` literal is just for testing and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) here. It could be `\w+` in real, but with 500.000+ lines in thousands of files when testing...

It works if I try it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/pIoGtE/5). Well, sort of. I didn't find how to define `/start-regex/,/end-regex/` there, so I added another `.*` in between.

I took the flags from there but I couldn't find a description whether `gawk` supports the flag syntax `/.../sU , /.../U` so I just gave it a try. A now deleted comment told me that no flavour of `awk` supports this.

I also tried it with `grep`:

```bash
$ grep --version
grep (GNU grep) 3.1
...
$ grep -nrPf types.grep *.java
```

with **types.grep**:

```bash
(?s).*class\s+\w+\s*<.*,.*,.*>.*{
```

which results in output of **singleline.java** only.

`(?s)` is `--perl-regexp, -P` syntax and `grep --help` claims to support this.

#### UPDATE

The solution in Ed Morton's answer works well but it turned out that there are auto-generated files with methods like:

```java
    /** more code before here */    
    public void setId(String value) {
        this.id = value;
    }

    /**
     * Gets a map that contains attributes that aren't bound to any typed property on this class.
     * 
     * <p>
     * the map is keyed by the name of the attribute and 
     * the value is the string value of the attribute.
     * 
     * the map returned by this method is live, and you can add new attribute
     * by updating the map directly. Because of this design, there's no setter.
     * 
     * 
     * @return
     *     always non-null
     */
    public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
        return otherAttributes;
    }
```

which give an output of e.g.:

```bash
AbstractAddressType.java:81:      * Gets a map that contains attributes that aren't bound to any typed property on this class.
AbstractAddressType.java:82:      * 
AbstractAddressType.java:83:      * <p>
AbstractAddressType.java:84:      * the map is keyed by the name of the attribute and 
AbstractAddressType.java:85:      * the value is the string value of the attribute.
AbstractAddressType.java:86:      * 
AbstractAddressType.java:87:      * the map returned by this method is live, and you can add new attribute
AbstractAddressType.java:88:      * by updating the map directly. Because of this design, there's no setter.
AbstractAddressType.java:89:      * 
AbstractAddressType.java:90:      * 
AbstractAddressType.java:91:      * @return
AbstractAddressType.java:92:      *     always non-null
AbstractAddressType.java:93:      */
AbstractAddressType.java:94:     public Map<QName, String> getOtherAttributes() {
```

and others with class comments and annotations like:

```java
/**
 * This class was generated by Apache CXF 3.3.4
 * 2020-11-30T12:03:21.251+01:00
 * Generated source version: 3.3.4
 *
 */
@WebService(targetNamespace = "urn:SZRServices", name = "SZR")
@XmlSeeAlso({at.gv.egov.pvp1.ObjectFactory.class, org.w3._2001._04.xmldsig_more_.ObjectFactory.class, ObjectFactory.class, org.xmlsoap.schemas.ws._2002._04.secext.ObjectFactory.class, org.w3._2000._09.xmldsig_.ObjectFactory.class, at.gv.e_government.reference.namespace.persondata._20020228_.ObjectFactory.class})
public interface SZR {
// more code after here
```

with an an output of e.g.:

```bash
SZR.java:13:  * This class was generated by Apache CXF 3.3.4
SZR.java:14:  * 2020-10-12T11:51:35.175+02:00
SZR.java:15:  * Generated source version: 3.3.4
SZR.java:16:  *
SZR.java:17:  */
SZR.java:18: @WebService(targetNamespace = "urn:SZRServices", name = "SZR")
SZR.java:19: @XmlSeeAlso({at.gv.egov.pvp1.ObjectFactory.class, org.w3._2001._04.xmldsig_more_.ObjectFactory.class, ObjectFactory.class, org.xmlsoap.schemas.ws._2002._04.secext.ObjectFactory.class, org.w3._2000._09.xmldsig_.ObjectFactory.class, at.gv.e_government.reference.namespace.persondata._20020228_.ObjectFactory.class})
```

Comment: If I had to do something like this I wouldn't try a single regex, I'd write a tiny state machine in perl. Top of my head 3 states "Looking for <", "Looking for ," and "Looking for >" - this handles the multiple line issues that are going to wreak havoc with a single regex :-)

Comment: @John3136 Thanks for the comment. A now deleted comment proposed to write a Java class parser, too. Can you (or someone else, for that matter) confirm, at least, that  it _should_ work with the Perl regex `(?s)`–that this idea was right?

Comment: for the grep command that you tried, you'll need `-z` option as well to match across multliple lines (I have NOT tried to fully understand the question, just giving a suggestion).. but, you'll need `-o` option as well to display only matched portion, you won't get line numbers in the output, there'll be an addition ASCII NUL character at end of every match, etc

Comment: if you can install https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep, you'll get much faster results, you can use `-U` option for multiline match (no need to use NUL as input line separator) along with line number in the output, etc

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using any POSIX awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ cat tst.awk
/[[:space:]]*class[[:space:]]*/ {
    inDef = 1
    fname = FILENAME
    sub(".*/","",fname)
    def = out = ""
}
inDef {
    out = out fname ":" FNR ": " $0 ORS

    # Remove comments (not perfect but should work for 99.9% of cases)
    sub("//.*","")
    gsub("/[*]|[*]/","\n")
    gsub(/\n[^\n]*\n/,"")

    def = def $0 ORS
    if ( /{/ ) {
        if ( gsub(/,/,"&",def) > 2 ) {
            printf "%s", out
        }
        inDef = 0
    }
}
```

```
$ find tmp -type f -name '*.java' -exec awk -f tst.awk {} +
multiple-lines.java:1: class ClazzA<R extends A,
multiple-lines.java:2:     S extends B<T>, T extends C<T>,
multiple-lines.java:3:     U extends D, W extends E,
multiple-lines.java:4:     X extends F, Y extends G, Z extends H>
multiple-lines.java:5:     extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {
single-line.java:1: class ClazzB<R extends A, S extends B<T>, T extends C<T>, U extends D, W extends E, X extends F, Y extends G, Z extends H> extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {
```

The above was run using this input:

```
$ head tmp/*
==> tmp/X-no-parameter.java <==
class ClazzC /* no type parameter */ extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<A, B> x) {
    // ... code ...
  }
}

==> tmp/X-one-parameter.java <==
class ClazzD<R extends A>  // only one type parameter
    extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<X, Y> x) {
    // ... code ...
  }
}

==> tmp/X-two-line-parameters.java <==
class ClazzF<R extends A,  // only two type parameters
    S extends B<T>>        // on two lines
    extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<X, Y> x) {
    // ... code ...
  }
}

==> tmp/X-two-parameters.java <==
class ClazzE<R extends A, S extends B<T>>  // only two type parameters
    extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<X, Y> x) {
    // ... code ...
  }
}

==> tmp/multiple-lines.java <==
class ClazzA<R extends A,
    S extends B<T>, T extends C<T>,
    U extends D, W extends E,
    X extends F, Y extends G, Z extends H>
    extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<Q, R> x) {
    // ... code ...
  }
}

==> tmp/single-line.java <==
class ClazzB<R extends A, S extends B<T>, T extends C<T>, U extends D, W extends E, X extends F, Y extends G, Z extends H> extends OtherClazz<S> implements I<T> {

  public void method(Type<Q, R> x) {
    // ... code ...
  }
}
```

The above is just a best effort without writing a parser for the language and just having the OPs posted sample input/output to go on for what needs to be handled.

Comment: Although I don't know (yet) what this does in every detail, it works like a charm after removing the `^` before `class`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Then you must have SOMETHING before `class` in your source code. If it's white space then replace `^` with `^[[:space:]]*` rather than removing it. If it's not white space then let me know what it is and I'll tell you how to handle it. Do not just remove the `^` though or you'll start getting undesirable results for partial matches. You're welcome.

Comment: Yes, I do. That's why I used just `/class` in the question. It could be (zero or more) [class modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-8.html#jls-ClassModifier) with annotations before the literals. Though I haven't seen any class with annotations on the same line so far. They're usually on previous lines.

Comment: OK, then using `/[[:space:]]*class[[:space:]]*/` will probably be good enough since this is just a best-effort solution anyway.

Comment: ...A bit like the state machine I suggested in the comments but in awk :-)

Comment: @EdMorton The bounty is yours! Thanks once again for your answer. Do you have an idea regarding the update to my question? (I'm very confident you do but do you also have time to take a look at the Q again?)

Comment: You're welcome. [chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions) are discouraged, you should put your question back as it was so it and my answer make sense to others searching the archives in future with similar issues and ask a new, followup question if you have one.

Answer (score 4):

**Note:** Presence of comments can cause these solutions to fail.

With `ripgrep` (https://github.com/BurntSushi/ripgrep)

```sh
rg -nU --no-heading '(?s)class\s+\w+\s*<[^{]*,[^{]*,[^{]*>[^{]*\{' *.java
```

- `-n` enables line numbering (this is the default if output is to the terminal)
- `-U` enables multiline matching
- `--no-heading` by default, `ripgrep` displays matching lines grouped under filename as a header, this option makes `ripgrep` behave like `GNU grep` with filename prefix for each output line
- `[^{]*` is used instead of `.*` to prevent matching `,` and `>` elsewhere in the file, otherwise lines like `public void method(Type<Q, R> x) {` will get matched
- `-m` option can be used to limit number of matches per input file, which will give an additional benefit of not having to search entire input file

If you use the above regexp with `GNU grep`, note that:

- `grep` matches only one line at a time. If you use `-z` option, `grep` will consider ASCII NUL as the record separator, which effectively gives you ability to match across multiple lines, assuming input doesn't have NUL characters that can prevent such matching. Another effect of `-z` option is that NUL character will be appended to each output result (this could be fixed by piping results to `tr '\0' '\n'`)
- `-o` option will be needed to print only matching portion, which means you won't be able to get line number prefix
- for the given task, `-P` isn't needed, `grep -zoE 'class\s+\w+\s*<[^{]*,[^{]*,[^{]*>[^{]*\{' *.java | tr '\0' '\n'` will give you similar result as the `ripgrep` command. But, you won't get line number prefix, filename prefix will be only for each matching portion instead of each matching line and you won't get rest of line before `class` and after `{`

Comment: Thanks for this answer including such detailed explanations. I'd really like to give you an extra bounty for it, showing my appreciation, but [I don't see anything I can do to achieve this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty). (Not even creating a few fake SO accounts to upvote your A will do it. :)

Comment: Getting a bounty would feel good. But I like answering on SO in general and this question was a nice learning experience too (especially Ed's answer, as always).

Comment: Those regexps would fail if a `,` or `{` appeared in the comments. Not sure if/how you could solve that problem with a regexp.

Comment: @EdMorton just added a note on that.. current solution will fail with presence of comment between `class` and `<` too.. one way to solve would be to remove the comments before applying this regex for matching.. there could be other ways with PCRE, but I'm not going to think/try it.. I modified OP's attempt for this answer..

Comment: Good point and if you removed the comments first then the line numbers could be off. Maybe there is a way to do it with a PCRE, idk, not something I've ever dabbled in or wanted to dabble in!